# Wix install to multiple remote machines

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm new to Wix and am wondering if there's a way to install files to several machines that are all on the same network from a single MSI?

The installer would prompt the user for all the machine names and then the installer would install on each of the machines.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft [Active directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory)'s Group policy is used exactly for this. For tutorial see for example [this](http://docs.trendmicro.com/all/ent/officescan/v10.6/en-us/osce_10.6_sp3_olh/ins_mth_msi.html) link.